# Create nested <p> tag in Jade JS without trailing newline

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

How does one do the following in Jade JS?

```
<div id="container">
    Temperature<p id = "temp">00.00</p>
</div>
```

i.e., create a nested tag without a newline.

I have tried:

```
// outputs newline
#container
    p#temp 00.00
```

and

```
// outputs literal p#temp text
#container p#temp 00.00
```

But it does not seem to work.  Indentation gives a parse error as well.  I have looked at the documentation but it does not seem to yield anything.

Comment: Use a `span` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#container
  |Temperature
  p#temp 00.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always just type the html inline:

```
//thermometer.jade
#container Temperature<p id="temp">#{locals.tempValue}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

A `span` is the way to go instead of a `p` tag

```
#container
    span#temp 00.00
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried though but it clears the "Temperature" text as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you must, you could use:

```
#container Temperature<p id='temp>00.00</p>
```

How and why is your whitespace significant?

Comment: I will be changing the text in JS.  It did not work though, p gets interpreted as literal.  Resorted instead to using `<em>`, but was wondering if there was a more jade-like way to code it.